# Plesk: access mysql as root

Tags: linux, mysql, vps

I cannot access MySQL as root on my Plesk 10.x + (Linux) VPS.  Apparently Plesk disables the `root` account and replaces it with `admin` with the same password as your Plesk login, but access is still denied!

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How can I get CLI access to MySQL if Plesk seemingly disables `root` access?

Comment: Don't use Plesk.  Or PHP, if you can help it.  You'll feel much better.

Comment: I completely agree on the Plesk, but I'm stuck with it, and I would love to learn something other than PHP.  If only time permitted me to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost correct.

Plesk actually uses the **hash** of your admin password as the plain MySQL password.

Obtain the hash by running `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` - the full string of resulting gibberish is your plaintext MySQL password.

Answer (score 4):

For Plesk 10.x, try the following command to gain aaccess to mysql

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

For more information, check the following link - http://kb.parallels.com/en/427